# creating a stroked shape

Tags: java, swing, canvas

I am having trouble with creating a stroked shape in `BasicStroke Outline = new BasicStroke(10f, 50, 50);`. The error I am currently getting is error:

> can't find symbol canvas.setStroke(Outline) pointing to the dot.

I am new to constructors so any help would be great and the only thing I did similar to this was creating an instance of `Scanner`.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color; //sets color
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
public class ColoredOlypmicRings extends JFrame
{
 //varriables go here


public void paint(Graphics canvas)
{
 super.paint (canvas);

canvas.setColor(Color.green);
canvas.drawOval(100,100,100,100); //color green
canvas.setColor(Color.red);
canvas.drawOval(200,200,100,100); //color red
final BasicStroke Outline = new BasicStroke(10f, 50, 50);
canvas.setStroke(Outline);

canvas.drawOval(300,300,200,200);
}

 public ColoredOlypmicRings()
 {
 setSize(600,400);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 }

public static void main(String[] args)
{
 ColoredOlypmicRings guiWindow = new ColoredOlypmicRings();
guiWindow.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

Comment: Check this sample example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/strokeandfill.html

Answer (score 3):

The [Graphics class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) can't handle Strokes and doesn't have methods for setting it as [its API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) will tell you.

The [Graphics2D class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) on the other hand can handle this class and should be used to handle it. So cast your Graphics object to a Graphics2D object.

e.g.,

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setStroke(....); // do it here after casting
}
```

Also check out the BasicStroke API as you're not using the constructor correctly, passing in incorrect parameters.

Other issues:

- Don't draw directly in a JFrame or other top-level window.
- Instead draw in the paintComnponent method of a JPanel that is displayed in the JFrame.
- The three int BasicStroke constructor is being mis-used  as the 2nd and 3rd parameters should be constants that represent the cap and join state of the Stroke object.